# SSL certificate installing

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate

Hi ALL  Apach2traid+ssl+cetificate:
I am trying to make a secure web page for payment
and this web page is for study purpose
so i thought that i may take a trial veriSign certificate
so after obtaining the certificate what should i do
and do it work if i am using my website only as localhost
finally i was told to mke a virtual server to make it run i tried the flowing

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
SSLCertificateFile C:\apache2triad\opssl\cert\my.cer  
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\apache2triad\opssl\cert\server.key
SSLCACertificateFile C:\apache2triad\opssl\cert\intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

this was in the httpd.conf
and after that the apache with ssl worker ok
but when i call a page with https
it didnt run
should i make some thing else rather than just put https

need some help and discussion please
thanks

Comment: serverfault.com has lots of apache experts, you may have luck posting there

Answer (score 1):

https connects on a different port number, 443, normal http request come to port 80.

```
<virtualHost localhost:443>
```

and you'll also need to make sure apache is listening on port 443, elsewhere in your httpd.conf

```
listen 127.0.0.1:80
listen 127.0.0.1:443
```

bets of luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer
i did that and restarted the server then i called
http://localhost:433/..../page.php
it worked put i didnt notice any thing different i mean green line (as this should be secure ..) 
i tried to call https it didnt work 
please help
thanks

Comment: after the modification to 
listen 127.0.0.1:80
listen 127.0.0.1:443

it refuses to lunch
even if i return back to localhost:443

Answer (score 1):

You missed (in the virtualhost):

```
SSLEngine on
```

As Fire Crow suggested, you'll also want to run it on 443. Whilst you *could* run HTTPS on port 80, it'd be a strange thing indeed.

Comment: THE overall procedure is not working 
i don't know why 
please can any one provide a way to make a secure web page using certificate from scrach thanks to your replays